# Java RSA/ECB/OAEPWITHSHA-256ANDMGF1PADDING Migrate To Go

Tags: java, go, rsa

I want to migrate a code from Java to Go, these methods should be able to cipher/decipher each others output, but they generate different results and can not decrypt other ones cipher:

**java Code**

```
public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] data, PublicKey publicKeyObject)
        throws BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException,
        InvalidKeyException, NoSuchPaddingException,
        NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher
            .getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWITHSHA-256ANDMGF1PADDING");

    OAEPParameterSpec oaepParameterSpec = new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256",
            "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA1, PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT);
    try {
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKeyObject,
                oaepParameterSpec);
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return cipher.doFinal(data);
}

private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] data, PrivateKey privateKeyObj)
        throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException,
        IllegalBlockSizeException {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher
            .getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWITHSHA-256ANDMGF1PADDING");

    OAEPParameterSpec oaepParameterSpec = new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256",
            "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA1, PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT);
    try {
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKeyObj, oaepParameterSpec);

    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    return cipher.doFinal(data);
}
```

**Go Code**

```
rng := rand.Reader

ciphertext, err := rsa.EncryptOAEP(sha256.New(), rng, rsaPublicKey, secretMessage, label)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Error from encryption: %s\n", err)
    return
}
clearText, err := rsa.DecryptOAEP(sha256.New(), rng, rsaPrivateKey, ciphertext, label)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Error from decryption: %s\n", err)
    return
}
```

I even tried sha1 as first parameter of **Go** but the results are difference.

can anybody help me with this?

Comment: What data does `label` contain in the Go Code?

Comment: Presumably, the Go code uses SHA256 for both the OAEP and MGF1 digest, while the Java code applies SHA256 for the OAEP digest and SHA-1 for the MGF1 digest.

Comment: RSA encryption is almost always randomized; you would expect it to generate different ciphertext even for different runs of the same code with the same key. That in itself is not an indicator of any sorts. The default Java provider has the nasty habit of keeping the MGF1 hash to SHA-1.

Comment: @Topaco thanks, your solution worked, I did submit a request at github for go dev team, can you please also provide encryption method?

Comment: @hmmftg - Please see my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why both codes are not compatible has already been explained in the comments and the  [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69287156/9014097): Go's crypto/rsa package, unlike the Java code, does not allow the *separate* specification of OAEP digest and MGF1 digest, resulting in different MGF1 digests being used in both codes.
In contrast, this answer should focus on the adaptation of the crypto/rsa package to fix the issue.

The meaning of both digests is described in RFC 8017, more precisely in section [*7.1 RSAES-OAEP*](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8017#section-7.1), where OAEP is defined.
As options and input parameters a digest (OAEP digest), a mask generation function, a label, the message and the public key are specified, s. [*7.1.1 Encryption Operation*](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8017#section-7.1.1). The OAEP digest is used to hash the label, s. [*7.1.1, Step 2a*](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8017#section-7.1.1). As mask generation function RFC 8017 defines MGF1 *exclusively* (s. [*B.2.1 MGF1*](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8017#appendix-B.2.1)), which is therefore generally used in OAEP. MGF1 is based on a digest (MGF1 digest).
RFC 8017 specifies the following default values, s. [*A.2.1 RSAES-OAEP*](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8017#appendix-A.2.1): MGF1, SHA1 for the OAEP and MGF1 digests, and an empty label.

Although SHA-1 is now deemed insecure, there are no known insecurities in the context of OAEP, s. [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/112032). Nevertheless, SHA256 is meanwhile often used, as a preventive measure or in the course of eliminating SHA-1 from the ecosystem.
Furthermore, RFC 8017 does not exclude the use of different digests for the OAEP and the MGF1 digest, as in your example.
Therefore, an implementation should allow the independent specification of both digests, which the crypto/rsa package fails to do.

To allow both digests to be specified separately, a second parameter must be used in the `EncryptOAEP()` and `DecryptOAEP()` functions to pass the MGF1 digest, which is then applied to MGF1:

```golang
func EncryptOAEP(hash hash.Hash, hashMGF1 hash.Hash, random io.Reader, pub *rsa.PublicKey, msg []byte, label []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    ...
    hashMGF1.Reset()
    mgf1XOR(seed, hashMGF1, db) 
    mgf1XOR(db, hashMGF1, seed) 
    ...
}
```

and analogously for `DecryptOAEP()`.

This could best be implemented with a corresponding adjustment of the crypto/rsa package itself. Alternatively, as a workaround, the required functions can be copied from the crypto/rsa package and adapted, as in the following code inclusive test:

```golang
package main

import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/subtle"
    "crypto/rsa"
    "crypto/sha256"
    "crypto/sha1"
    "crypto/x509"
    "encoding/pem"
    "encoding/base64"
    "hash"
    "errors"
    "io"
    "math/big"
    "sync"
    "fmt"
    )

func main() {

    var publicKeyData = `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAoZ67dtUTLxoXnNEzRBFB
mwukEJGC+y69cGgpNbtElQj3m4Aft/7cu9qYbTNguTSnCDt7uovZNb21u1vpZwKH
yVgFEGO4SA8RNnjhJt2D7z8RDMWX3saody7jo9TKlrPABLZGo2o8vadW8Dly/v+I
d0YDheCkVCoCEeUjQ8koXZhTwhYkGPu+vkdiqX5cUaiVTu1uzt591aO5Vw/hV4DI
hFKnOTnYXnpXiwRwtPyYoGTa64yWfi2t0bv99qz0BgDjQjD0civCe8LRXGGhyB1U
1aHjDDGEnulTYJyEqCzNGwBpzEHUjqIOXElFjt55AFGpCHAuyuoXoP3gQvoSj6RC
sQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`

    var privateKeyData = `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`
    
    secretMessage := []byte("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog")
    label := []byte("")
    rng := rand.Reader

    // Encryption -------------------------------------------------------------
    
    // Load public key
    pubKeyBlock, _ := pem.Decode([]byte(publicKeyData))
    var rsaPublicKey *rsa.PublicKey
    pubInterface, parseErr := x509.ParsePKIXPublicKey(pubKeyBlock.Bytes)
    if parseErr != nil {
        fmt.Println("Load public key error")
        panic(parseErr)
    }
    rsaPublicKey = pubInterface.(*rsa.PublicKey)

    ciphertext, err := EncryptOAEP(sha256.New(), sha1.New(), rng, rsaPublicKey, secretMessage, label)
    if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error from encryption: %s\n", err)
            return
    }

    // Decryption -------------------------------------------------------------
    
    // Load private key
    privateKeyBlock, _ := pem.Decode([]byte(privateKeyData))
    var rsaPrivateKey *rsa.PrivateKey
    rsaPrivateKey, _ = x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey(privateKeyBlock.Bytes)
    
    decrypted, err := DecryptOAEP(sha256.New(), sha1.New(), rng, rsaPrivateKey, ciphertext, label)
    if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error from decryption: %s\n", err)
            return
    }
    fmt.Println("Go Encryption/Decryption : " + string(decrypted))  
    
    // Cross-platform test: ciphertext from Java
    /*
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWITHSHA-256ANDMGF1PADDING");
        OAEPParameterSpec oaepParameterSpec = new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA1, PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKeyObject, oaepParameterSpec);
        String ciphertextB64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(data));
    */
    ciphertext,_ = base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString("cCrJasWOwVFrAQ8S+p7Cdn7OnCJn/FiCjZLzDkDISOSv15u1HcLbVAqNa7ory2AW/tsV5tNz5Y53azs6SN7dwYlu58YH7kwqkwfmvUwK8pLdPPRXGaUy8/gEbM4wkwHUuxbYm/bpoEjpmICBtWzb5VOsE1RWHnZu1G2BqGKe1+sE1XadVKQpBqNSahYdthY2Dk21i/PStO5S4eRrgW2nDdmxCs9UtV4MBU8BVYHYF0TYweA/udBoGTizSDjgmWn0RXYJruGvFMHWCRRlPnj+pcelatIfY4YKOHREYifKVkphkB7PT/JaVFyMZWzOtqzE13ZBWBwBmA/yCNLE/7krcg==")  
    decrypted, err = DecryptOAEP(sha256.New(), sha1.New(), rng, rsaPrivateKey, ciphertext, label)
    if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error from decryption: %s\n", err)
            return
    }
    fmt.Println("Cross platform decryption: " + string(decrypted))  
    

}

// From rsa package - Encryption -------------------------------------------------------------

func EncryptOAEP(hash hash.Hash, hashMGF1 hash.Hash, random io.Reader, pub *rsa.PublicKey, msg []byte, label []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    if err := checkPub(pub); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    hash.Reset()
    k := pub.Size()
    if len(msg) > k-2*hash.Size()-2 {
        return nil, rsa.ErrMessageTooLong
    }

    hash.Write(label)
    lHash := hash.Sum(nil)
    hash.Reset()

    em := make([]byte, k)
    seed := em[1 : 1+hash.Size()]
    db := em[1+hash.Size():]

    copy(db[0:hash.Size()], lHash)
    db[len(db)-len(msg)-1] = 1
    copy(db[len(db)-len(msg):], msg)

    _, err := io.ReadFull(random, seed)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    hashMGF1.Reset()
    mgf1XOR(db, hashMGF1, seed)
    mgf1XOR(seed, hashMGF1, db)

    m := new(big.Int)
    m.SetBytes(em)
    c := encrypt(new(big.Int), pub, m)

    out := make([]byte, k)
    return c.FillBytes(out), nil
}

func encrypt(c *big.Int, pub *rsa.PublicKey, m *big.Int) *big.Int {
    e := big.NewInt(int64(pub.E))
    c.Exp(m, e, pub.N)
    return c
}

// From rsa package - Decryption -------------------------------------------------------------

func DecryptOAEP(hash hash.Hash, hashMGF1 hash.Hash, random io.Reader, priv *rsa.PrivateKey, ciphertext []byte, label []byte) ([]byte, error) { // hashMGF1 hash.Hash added
    if err := checkPub(&priv.PublicKey); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    k := priv.Size()
    if len(ciphertext) > k ||
        k < hash.Size()*2+2 {
        return nil, rsa.ErrDecryption
    }

    c := new(big.Int).SetBytes(ciphertext)

    m, err := decrypt(random, priv, c)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    hash.Write(label)
    lHash := hash.Sum(nil)
    hash.Reset()

    // We probably leak the number of leading zeros.
    // It's not clear that we can do anything about this.
    em := m.FillBytes(make([]byte, k))

    firstByteIsZero := subtle.ConstantTimeByteEq(em[0], 0)

    seed := em[1 : hash.Size()+1]
    db := em[hash.Size()+1:]

    hashMGF1.Reset()
    mgf1XOR(seed, hashMGF1, db) // apply hashMGF1
    mgf1XOR(db, hashMGF1, seed) // apply hashMGF1

    lHash2 := db[0:hash.Size()]

    // We have to validate the plaintext in constant time in order to avoid
    // attacks like: J. Manger. A Chosen Ciphertext Attack on RSA Optimal
    // Asymmetric Encryption Padding (OAEP) as Standardized in PKCS #1
    // v2.0. In J. Kilian, editor, Advances in Cryptology.
    lHash2Good := subtle.ConstantTimeCompare(lHash, lHash2)

    // The remainder of the plaintext must be zero or more 0x00, followed
    // by 0x01, followed by the message.
    //   lookingForIndex: 1 iff we are still looking for the 0x01
    //   index: the offset of the first 0x01 byte
    //   invalid: 1 iff we saw a non-zero byte before the 0x01.
    var lookingForIndex, index, invalid int
    lookingForIndex = 1
    rest := db[hash.Size():]

    for i := 0; i < len(rest); i++ {
        equals0 := subtle.ConstantTimeByteEq(rest[i], 0)
        equals1 := subtle.ConstantTimeByteEq(rest[i], 1)
        index = subtle.ConstantTimeSelect(lookingForIndex&equals1, i, index)
        lookingForIndex = subtle.ConstantTimeSelect(equals1, 0, lookingForIndex)
        invalid = subtle.ConstantTimeSelect(lookingForIndex&^equals0, 1, invalid)
    }

    if firstByteIsZero&lHash2Good&^invalid&^lookingForIndex != 1 {
        return nil, rsa.ErrDecryption
    }

    return rest[index+1:], nil
}

var bigZero = big.NewInt(0)
var bigOne = big.NewInt(1)

func decrypt(random io.Reader, priv *rsa.PrivateKey, c *big.Int) (m *big.Int, err error) {
    // TODO(agl): can we get away with reusing blinds?
    if c.Cmp(priv.N) > 0 {
        err = rsa.ErrDecryption
        return
    }
    if priv.N.Sign() == 0 {
        return nil, rsa.ErrDecryption
    }

    var ir *big.Int
    if random != nil {
        MaybeReadByte(random)

        // Blinding enabled. Blinding involves multiplying c by r^e.
        // Then the decryption operation performs (m^e * r^e)^d mod n
        // which equals mr mod n. The factor of r can then be removed
        // by multiplying by the multiplicative inverse of r.

        var r *big.Int
        ir = new(big.Int)
        for {
            r, err = rand.Int(random, priv.N)
            if err != nil {
                return
            }
            if r.Cmp(bigZero) == 0 {
                r = bigOne
            }
            ok := ir.ModInverse(r, priv.N)
            if ok != nil {
                break
            }
        }
        bigE := big.NewInt(int64(priv.E))
        rpowe := new(big.Int).Exp(r, bigE, priv.N) // N != 0
        cCopy := new(big.Int).Set(c)
        cCopy.Mul(cCopy, rpowe)
        cCopy.Mod(cCopy, priv.N)
        c = cCopy
    }

    if priv.Precomputed.Dp == nil {
        m = new(big.Int).Exp(c, priv.D, priv.N)
    } else {
        // We have the precalculated values needed for the CRT.
        m = new(big.Int).Exp(c, priv.Precomputed.Dp, priv.Primes[0])
        m2 := new(big.Int).Exp(c, priv.Precomputed.Dq, priv.Primes[1])
        m.Sub(m, m2)
        if m.Sign() < 0 {
            m.Add(m, priv.Primes[0])
        }
        m.Mul(m, priv.Precomputed.Qinv)
        m.Mod(m, priv.Primes[0])
        m.Mul(m, priv.Primes[1])
        m.Add(m, m2)

        for i, values := range priv.Precomputed.CRTValues {
            prime := priv.Primes[2+i]
            m2.Exp(c, values.Exp, prime)
            m2.Sub(m2, m)
            m2.Mul(m2, values.Coeff)
            m2.Mod(m2, prime)
            if m2.Sign() < 0 {
                m2.Add(m2, prime)
            }
            m2.Mul(m2, values.R)
            m.Add(m, m2)
        }
    }

    if ir != nil {
        // Unblind.
        m.Mul(m, ir)
        m.Mod(m, priv.N)
    }

    return
}

var (
    closedChanOnce sync.Once
    closedChan     chan struct{}
)

func MaybeReadByte(r io.Reader) { // from "crypto/internal/randutil"
    closedChanOnce.Do(func() {
        closedChan = make(chan struct{})
        close(closedChan)
    })

    select {
    case <-closedChan:
        return
    case <-closedChan:
        var buf [1]byte
        r.Read(buf[:])
    }
}

// From rsa package - both -------------------------------------------------------------

func mgf1XOR(out []byte, hash hash.Hash, seed []byte) {
    var counter [4]byte
    var digest []byte

    done := 0
    for done < len(out) {
        hash.Write(seed)
        hash.Write(counter[0:4])
        digest = hash.Sum(digest[:0])
        hash.Reset()

        for i := 0; i < len(digest) && done < len(out); i++ {
            out[done] ^= digest[i]
            done++
        }
        incCounter(&counter)
    }
}

func checkPub(pub *rsa.PublicKey) error {
    if pub.N == nil {
        return errPublicModulus
    }
    if pub.E < 2 {
        return errPublicExponentSmall
    }
    if pub.E > 1<<31-1 {
        return errPublicExponentLarge
    }
    return nil
}

var (
    errPublicModulus       = errors.New("crypto/rsa: missing public modulus")
    errPublicExponentSmall = errors.New("crypto/rsa: public exponent too small")
    errPublicExponentLarge = errors.New("crypto/rsa: public exponent too large")
)

func incCounter(c *[4]byte) {
    if c[3]++; c[3] != 0 {
        return
    }
    if c[2]++; c[2] != 0 {
        return
    }
    if c[1]++; c[1] != 0 {
        return
    }
    c[0]++
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not set up to test Go, but a common incompatibility with OAEP is to infer that the MGF hash is the same as the "main" hash when it isn't specified, rather than defaulting to SHA-1.

In other words, there are two hash algorithms in use, and they can be chosen independently, but the Go API may not give you this flexibility. If you choose SHA-1, perhaps it uses SHA-1 for both functions, and if you choose SHA-256, it's used for both functions, while your Java code uses both together.

As a debugging strategy, you could encode parameters on each platform and inspect the data to determine any difference in the parameters. Again, I'm not familiar with the Go API, but it would be best to encode the OAEP parameters used during encryption, and send them with the message, so the recipient can decode the correct parameters instead of guessing.

Using [CMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_Message_Syntax) or equivalent standards would give you a standard format for transmitting this information, as well as key identifiers and other important information to recipients.