# RSA Encryption/Decryption between Python and Golang not working?

Tags: python, go, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

When I encrypt a string with Go, I am unable to decrypt it again with Python.  I'm clearly doing something wrong, but I'm unable to identify the problem.  Any assistance greatly appreciated.

Essentially, I'm encrypting a string with the following function (which I'm then able to decrypt with Go, but not Python):

```golang
func encryptString(s string) string {
    publicKey, _ := os.ReadFile("public.pem")
    block, _ := pem.Decode([]byte(publicKey))
    if block.Type != "PUBLIC KEY" {
        log.Fatal("error decoding public key from pem")
    }
    parsedKey, err := x509.ParsePKIXPublicKey(block.Bytes)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("error parsing key")
    }
    var ok bool
    var pubkey *rsa.PublicKey
    if pubkey, ok = parsedKey.(*rsa.PublicKey); !ok {
        log.Fatal("unable to parse public key")
    }
    rng := rand.Reader
    ciphertext, err := rsa.EncryptOAEP(sha256.New(), rng, pubkey, []byte(s), nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(ciphertext)
}
```

This is the python code I'm using to try and decode the encrypted string:

```py
import os
import base64
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.padding import MGF1, OAEP
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.rsa import RSAPrivateKey
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import load_pem_private_key

encrypted_message = "<REMOVED>"
encrypted_message_bytes = base64.b64decode(encrypted_message.encode("utf-8"))
PRIVATE_KEY = os.getenv("PRIVATE_KEY")
private_key_bytes = PRIVATE_KEY.encode("utf-8")
private_key: RSAPrivateKey = load_pem_private_key(private_key_bytes, None)
padding = OAEP(mgf=MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()), algorithm=hashes.SHA256(), label=None)
decrypted_message = private_key.decrypt(encrypted_message_bytes, padding)
print(decrypted_message)
```

On running this, I just get the following error:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "decrypt_test.py", line 14, in <module>
    decrypted_message = private_key.decrypt(encrypted_message_bytes, padding)
  File "venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/rsa.py", line 424, in decrypt
    return _enc_dec_rsa(self._backend, self, ciphertext, padding)
  File "venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/rsa.py", line 87, in _enc_dec_rsa
    return _enc_dec_rsa_pkey_ctx(backend, key, data, padding_enum, padding)
  File "venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/rsa.py", line 151, in _enc_dec_rsa_pkey_ctx
    raise ValueError("Encryption/decryption failed.")
ValueError: Encryption/decryption failed.
```

I don't have any control over the python code in production, so I would like to only make changes to Go code.  I also have the same problem the other way around, but I expect it's the same issue.

Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

Comment: OAEP unfortunately proved to be too complex for many implementers and as a result some implementations make assumptions about the MGF1 hash, namely that it should be SHA1. I'm not familiar with Go's crypto so I would just try the python decryptor with `OAEP(mgf=MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA1()), algorithm=hashes.SHA256(), ...`. If that doesn't work (the answer below suggests this isn't the problem) then other possibilities include mismatched public/private keys or ciphertext corruption.

Comment: `rsa.EncryptOAEP()` uses the digest specified in the first parameter for _both_ digests applied in the OAEP context (s. e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69333971/9014097)), so here SHA256, which is thus compatible with the Python code. I can't reproduce the problem with my keys either (in agreement with the posted answer), so most likely the codes themselves are not the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what changed, but when I revisited this, it did start working.  I did change the way I was loading the certificate files etc. and so there may have been an issue there with mismatched keys or something like that as suggested here.  I can confirm performing encryption/decryption between python/Go does work.  Thanks to those that responded.

Answer (score 1):

A private key in pem format has multi lines, maybe you could try to read the private key from file

```py
PRIVATE_KEY = open('./private.pem', 'r').read()
```

The codes below worked on my test server

encrypt.go

```golang
package main

import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/rsa"
    "crypto/sha256"
    "crypto/x509"
    "encoding/base64"
    "encoding/pem"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    s := "heloo"
    publicKey, _ := os.ReadFile("./rsa_public_key.pem")
    block, _ := pem.Decode([]byte(publicKey))
    if block.Type != "PUBLIC KEY" {
        log.Fatal("error decoding public key from pem")
    }
    parsedKey, err := x509.ParsePKIXPublicKey(block.Bytes)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("error parsing key")
    }
    var ok bool
    var pubkey *rsa.PublicKey
    if pubkey, ok = parsedKey.(*rsa.PublicKey); !ok {
        log.Fatal("unable to parse public key")
    }
    rng := rand.Reader
    ciphertext, err := rsa.EncryptOAEP(sha256.New(), rng, pubkey, []byte(s), nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(ciphertext))
}
```

decrypt.py

```
import base64
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.padding import MGF1, OAEP
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.rsa import RSAPrivateKey
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import load_pem_private_key

encrypted_message = "CQMKIcEnqtkvyduwtVNNzdEH23DlQVBaI1rbo/5TA1syW4/ZUyXuHmGTuxqK6+d0gqF7/l2uFGoCY/gQ6FFaVk2JTZqJwYbX5AzZRYI77PuZdjhSROT01LIdDgdRJqO9kqDcIRr1M2b7tRp9a3nF6LwhL9DdX7Z9P1qnNHUEE30="
encrypted_message_bytes = base64.b64decode(encrypted_message.encode("utf-8"))
PRIVATE_KEY = open('./rsa_private_key.pem', 'r').read()
private_key_bytes = PRIVATE_KEY.encode("utf-8")
private_key: RSAPrivateKey = load_pem_private_key(private_key_bytes, None)
padding = OAEP(mgf=MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()), algorithm=hashes.SHA256(), label=None)
decrypted_message = private_key.decrypt(encrypted_message_bytes, padding)
print(decrypted_message)
```

commands used to generate RSA keys

```
openssl genrsa -out rsa_private_key.pem 1024
openssl rsa -in rsa_private_key.pem -pubout -out rsa_public_key.pem
```

cat ./rsa_private_key.pem

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

cat ./rsa_public_key.pem

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDabYklPLIPvrwmPpuQZcIjfEnO
Lq5YtSdOzvDRrFcd0XXBz2VcTHC+VzgE38l5DqMagdhea0/2UNRBIEQrpLPNwNbv
Va7eRmgzOnv3P7R4ylOLorkwCLpUedOHJ+9pe8mbJ2Z4npKw0Y+JPuqgNY1ZB/Pc
qaajCoZHgTvdYe14DwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

```
$ go run ./encrypt.go
wgM33DAJABF0MC0BkflewXPABVdyWpzYMsYhMVKs13OS7SB+fkW31kxL7dipxxEqmTPWXCGFu8o3QxDY82VgcfEywSdigml22KXUN1Qg1VIU6yZg6i34wuD07/8zalW+pza9F43Mj0/XRKnn10ZagfgkBYaytk1zQ4cKcYp4JrM=
```

```
$ python3 ./decrypt.py
b'heloo'
```

Comment: The error occurs in private_key.decrypt, not load_pem_private_key.

Comment: @Peter I have verified on my test server

Comment: @emptyhua can you share the decrypt code for golang too